# Посчитать кол-во input:checked в документе и вывести это число в span JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть три чекбокса. Один по умолчанию input:checked, два других нет. Нужно показывать на страничке сколько input:checked штук. Если включено два - то цифра должна появляться 2 и т.д. Кол-во я нашла с помощью длинны массива var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'); а как теперь обновлять данные о включенных чекбоксах и перезаписывать инфо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var checked;
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  checked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
  console.log(checked.length);
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!!!